# Introducing Scrum in a distributed team

Tags: agile

We would like to start using scrum in our distributed development team. Until know we used a "home-grown" methodology, but we would like to switch to something more defined and mature. Scrum would be a great choice in my opinion and also the management supports us to go agile.

Where should we start this transition? Is there some guide or best practices for this transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into receiving formal training from the Scrum Alliance:

http://www.scrumalliance.org

It's an organization that offers training and certification for the different roles in Scrum such as Scrum Master and Product Owner. I think that since your team is looking into starting with with Scrum from a home-grown methodology, investing in training from an established organization can help you get a great start, and their coaches might also be able to provide specific tips for your situation, such as your distributed team.

Comment: This is something we can't do at the moment. I am just looking for some guidance and tips for introducing scrum.

Comment: In that case for a very quick and high level introduction I suggest this video called Scrum In Under 10 Minutes. It provides a very clear and concise explanation of the methodology. My old team watched this video prior to receiving Scrum Master certifications. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XU0llRltyFM

Comment: Actually I know Scrum. I am just curious how to start introducing it. Just train the team members then define backlog items and start the first sprint?

Comment: I'd start with the video first for your team members completely unfamiliar with Scrum, then yes I'd jump right in with the first planning session and sprint. Your burndown might be a but slow as your team gets the hang of it, but velocity and any specific questions can be addressed in the first retrospective. Personally I think the best way to learn something is to do it, so I agree with you in just getting a sprint going.